# Why is Stripe subscription not activated when using 3D secure credit card?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am using to [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js) to charge my customers.

My code works for **SEPA direct debits** and *normal* **credit cards**, however it fails for **3D secure cards** and I don't quite understand why. When I enter Stripe's 3D secure test card number (`4000 0000 0000 3220`), VISA's confirmation pop-up appears and I can select `Confirm` but after doing so the pop-up simply disappears and nothing else happens. The customer's subscription is not activated or confirmed anywhere in the logs. How can this be fixed? Is there something wrong in my code?

```
const tag = document.querySelector('meta[name=stripe-publishable-key]');

const key = tag.getAttribute('content');
const stripe = Stripe(key);

const form = document.querySelector('#stripe_form');

const name = document.querySelector('#name');
const email = document.querySelector('#email');

const payment = document.querySelector('#payment');
const errorMessage = document.querySelector('#stripe_error_message');
const clientSecret = document.querySelector('#client_secret');

const elements = stripe.elements();

const card = elements.create('card', {});

card.mount('#card');

const iban = elements.create('iban', {
  supportedCountries: ['SEPA'],
  placeholderCountry: 'FR'
});

iban.mount('#iban');

for (element of [card, iban]) {

  element.on("change", function(event) {
    if (event.error) {
      errorMessage.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      errorMessage.textContent = "";
    }
  });
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setupPaymentMethod(clientSecret.value, payment, {
    card: card,
    sepa_debit: iban
  });
});

function setupPaymentMethod(setupIntentSecret, paymentMethod, element) {
  switch (paymentMethod) {
    case "card":
      stripe.confirmCardSetup(setupIntentSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: element[paymentMethod],
          billing_details: {
            name: name.value,
            email: email.value
          }
        }
      })
      .then(handleResult);
    break;
    case "sepa_debit":
      stripe.confirmSepaDebitSetup(setupIntentSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          sepa_debit: element[paymentMethod],
          billing_details: {
            name: name.value,
            email: email.value
          }
        }
      })
      .then(handleResult);
    break;
    default:
      console.warn("Unhandled Payment Method!");
    break;
  }
}

function handleResult(result) {
  // console.log(result);
  if (result.error) {
    errorMessage.textContent = result.error.message;
  } else {
    let paymentMethod = document.createElement('input');
    paymentMethod.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    paymentMethod.setAttribute('name', 'payment_method');
    paymentMethod.value = result.setupIntent.payment_method;
    form.appendChild(paymentMethod);
    form.submit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know without seeing the requests, errors, etc.  Can you write into Support with the details so they can look into it for you?  https://support.stripe.com/contact/email

Comment: @Tintin81 there are usually some developers around on their freenode that are really helpful with this sort of thing. Though there are some issues surrounding freenode right now unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Is it enabled in the settings? This should at least add a popup window where the user has to confirm: https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/automatic

https://support.stripe.com/questions/using-3d-secure-authentication-with-payments-made-through-stripe-billing